# What does prime mean in the notation $k(x,x')$ in the context of kernels?

Tags: kernel-trick, notation

I admit it's a very specific question, but what is meant by the notation $'$ in Bishop's book *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*? I'd always thought it's a transpose, but this marked by a $^{T}$.

In Bishop's book, it is used in the context of kernels, e.g. $k(x,x')=\phi(x)^{T}\phi(x')$.

Since I can't provide a link to the book, you can [find here 
a presentation](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/~jegou/bishopreadinggroup/chap6.pdf) where this notation is used (slide 3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the prime notation means another point in the dataset. Instead of saying the similarity $k(x,y)$ between $x$ and $y$, it says $k(x,x')$ between $x$ and $x'$.